# manage.py sql command for django models - Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-manage.py

just wondering... but is it possible to generate SQL commands for django's models?

e.g. the session model

```
python manage.py sql django
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You need to mention the name of the specific app that comes with django, such as

```
 python manage.py sql auth
 python manage.py sql admin
```

I find it a bit clumsy that you can't give fully-qualified names (such as django.contrib.auth), but using just the last part of the name seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer possible with django migrations (django>=1.7).  The sql management command is no longer available.

Though it operates slightly differently, the sqlmigrate management command can be used to find the sql commands for individual migrations.

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate auth  0001
./manage.py sqlmigrate auth  0002
...
```